# Disable Sound in Phonegap Pushplugin

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-pushplugin

I have a phonegap app that uses the pushplugin to receive push notifications. Everything works great, but I now need the option to turn off the sound when a notification is received on an Android device. Not sure how to implement this, and searching the web is not helping.

Hoping somebody can help shed light on this...

Comment: I'd also like to learn how to do this.

Comment: Check this [pull request](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/pull/15)